# Hide simpleCart headers in emails

Tags: php, javascript, email, cart

When I send emails to customers, all of the cart headers appear like this:

> id=c2||name=Information||price=()||quantity=1

On the website, we hide the headers with `.cartHeaders{display:none;}`, but many email clients ignore CSS. I know it's in the simplecart.js file, but I can't find how to simply hide the cart headers all together.

Any suggestions?

Comment: In each of the headers, use the `style` attribute (`style="display:none;"`). Email styling is a major PITA. Especially when you try to verify that everything looks right in the majority of email clients.

Comment: @Matt I've tried <style>.cartHeaders{display:none;}</style> but I only get the raw cart returned.

Comment: Not the `<style>` tag - the `style` attribute of the individual element. `<div class="cartHeaders" style="display:none;"></div>`[This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894081/compile-css-into-html-as-inline-styles).

Comment: Ah right. I send the cart by putting this in the form: `<div class="simpleCart_items">`. And that populates all the information. So I can't do a `(style="display:none;")` because then it will display nothing at all.